# android include more layout,the programe dead

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, include

--tt.xml

```
<ViewFlipper android:layout_weight="36"
android:id="@+id/viewcontainer" android:measureAllChildren="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="80dp"
android:persistentDrawingCache="animation"  android:flipInterval="500">
<include layout="@layout/remotecontrol_pv_layout" />                
<include layout="@layout/remotecontrol_number_layout" />
<include layout="@layout/voicecontrol_layout" />
<include layout="@layout/mousecontrol_layout" />
<include layout="@layout/keyboardcontrol_layout" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

----in the activity.java
setContentView(R.layout.tt);when i debug this programe,the programe just dead,with no log,no error,no exception,then i change the code like this,the same , to test if there's a problem :

```
<ViewFlipper android:layout_weight="36"
android:id="@+id/viewcontainer" android:measureAllChildren="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="80dp"
android:persistentDrawingCache="animation"  android:flipInterval="500">
<include layout="@layout/remotecontrol_pv_layout" />                
<include layout="@layout/remotecontrol_pv_layout" />
<include layout="@layout/remotecontrol_pv_layout" />
<include layout="@layout/remotecontrol_pv_layout" />
<include layout="@layout/remotecontrol_pv_layout" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

---this time it works good.why??

Comment: What do you mean "the program just dead?"

Answer (score 0):

works out!
OOM error,out of memory,there are too many layouts